# display array string using for in android

Tags: android, arrays, for-loop, display

i want to make a simple quiz apps in android,but i find some difficulties in displaying my question. I use array of String to keep my question and try to display it with array. 
Here is my code

Here is my Error Log

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.hikaru.sistempakar, PID: 2626
>                                                                                 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
>                                                                                     at com.example.hikaru.sistempakar.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tv;
Button btn;
RadioGroup rg;
RadioButton rb1,rb2;
String questions[]={"Kulit Memerah?","Kulit Gatal?","Kulit Bersisik?","Kulit Menggumpal?","Kulit Melemouble?","Kulit Menebal?","Iritasi Kulit?"};
String opt[]={"Ya","Tidak"};
String ans[]={};

int flag=0;
int i=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
    rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    tv.setText(questions[flag]);
    rb1.setText(opt[0]);
    rb2.setText(opt[1]);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // RadioButton uans=(RadioButton)findViewById(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            //String ansText=uans.getText().toString();

            for(flag=0;flag<=questions.length;flag++)
            {
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[0]);
                rb2.setText(opt[1]);

            }
            //Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ResultActivity.class);
            //startActivity(in);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: when i run it,item that displayed just item in index 0 of array then the apps is force closing

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.hikaru.sistempakar, PID: 2626
                                                                              java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
                                                                                  at com.example.hikaru.sistempakar.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:46)

Comment: Change loop condition to `flag<questions.length`, remove `=`.

Comment: still not work,i've try it before... ._.a

Comment: Because you are running the same loop over and over again on button click.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? With one click of a button, you're going through all question in a loop.

Comment: i want to show the question one by one with the "next" button

Comment: @PanduPratamaNur check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code. This will keep on looping your questions on button click.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv;
    Button btn;
    RadioGroup rg;
    RadioButton rb1,rb2;
    String questions[]={"Kulit Memerah?","Kulit Gatal?","Kulit Bersisik?","Kulit Menggumpal?","Kulit Melemouble?","Kulit Menebal?","Iritasi Kulit?"};
    String opt[]={"Ya","Tidak"};
    String ans[]={};

    int flag=0;
    int i=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        rb1=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        rg=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

        tv.setText(questions[flag]);
        rb1.setText(opt[0]);
        rb2.setText(opt[1]);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag++;
                if(flag >= questions.length()){
                    flag=0;
                }
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When your flag value reaches 7, it checks for the condition `flag<=questions.length` which will return true but you don't actually have a 7th item in your array. This is the reason for your error.

Change your code to :

```
for(flag=0;flag<questions.length;flag++)
            {
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[0]);
                rb2.setText(opt[1]);

            }
```

or

```
for(flag=1;flag<=questions.length;flag++)
            {
                tv.setText(questions[flag]);
                rb1.setText(opt[0]);
                rb2.setText(opt[1]);

            }
```

Comment: 2nd option will still throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: thanks..it didnt force close but just index 0 and last index can that displayed,index 1 - 6 cant show...what is the cause?